# Python - Shortest way to write / Most creative way to write / Fastest code to process

Tags: python, performance, process, short

exploring Python.  I've been trying to always produce the same functionality through writing the least amount of code as a way to drive my advancement, but I'm looking to branch into an understanding of process speed and also just an awareness of perhaps less known, but still very useful, python keywords.  As such:

1. What's the shortest way to write this?
2. What's the best way to write this so that it'll process the fastest?
3. And just a little addition for fun, what's an irregular but efficient way to write this?

NOTE: While it may not be a popular view, I don't care about readability as I feel this is relative factor dependent upon ones skill in a language.

```
def xyFill(listObj, x, y):
    for row in listObj:
        x.append(row[0])
        y.append(row[1])
```

Comment: `as I feel this is relative factor dependent upon ones skill in a language.` someone need to read his own code 6 months later...

Comment: "While it may not be a popular view, I don't care about readability..." You're right. This is not going to be a popular view. :-)

Comment: Isn't this a topic for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @UmNyobe exactly, see my answer. I hope he reads it!

Comment: "" @qwrrty I read that and thought "crap, we must fix him!"

Answer (score 5):

If you are extending both `x` and `y` with `listObj` being two-value tuples, you can use:

```
new_x, new_y = zip(*lintObj)
x.extend(new_x)
y.extend(new_y)
```

If `x` and `y` were empty to start with, I'd just *return* the output of `zip(*lintObj)` and let the caller of the function sort this out:

```
def xyFill(lintObj):
    return zip(*lintObj)

x, y = xyFill(some_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

Short code = BAD.

It used to be good, back in the early days of C writing really compact code was great.

Now-a-days NO!

We write code to be easy to read. we let the compiler (or interpreter in your case) do what we write as fast as it can. Even Python's peep-hole optimiser does this well.

Python is VERY and BEAUTIFULLY object orientated. Go with this. Write code to be re-used where people using it can tell what it does (but not necessarily how it works) just from names of methods and variables.

Short compact code = bad. In lower-level languages (because Python is by no means a toy, it's a superb language) we don't write assembly for fast parts because we suck at that now. We write what we want to do clearly, and use the right algorithm and such, do not get involved in the rest. The compiler can allocate registers better than us, we shouldn't even try.

Python has a peep-hole optimiser that brings it as high-performance as a stack-based virtual machine can get. It also has some weird look-ahead and a cache.

In both the interpreted and compiled world **A LOT** of work has gone into reducing the penalty of abstraction, because abstraction objects and code-reuse = great code :)

Comment: @Robert I expect you to upvote, repent and accept. :p